# Applying function to each row of dataframe, merging data and writting to csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, apply

### Goal

I have a dataframe in R, my goal is for each row of the dataframe to perform an API call, retrieving data in csv format, then merge the two dataframe and append the newly formatted row to a csv file.
I ve been using `apply` function to loop over each row of the original df but Ive been struggling to merge the two resulting dfs and append to the file.

First, the row input to my get_temp function seem to be a vector of characters. The response from the api call seem to be automatically converted to a `dataframe` by function `read_csv`. My goal is just to **merge the two side by side**. I guess I would need to convert row vector to a dataframe but I am actually not sure this is the right approach and I have been struggling to do that.

Here's the bit of relevent code I wrote to try to achieve that :

```
get_temp <- function(row) {
    uri <- build_uri(latitude, longitude, start_date)
    response <- read_csv(uri)
    merged <- merge(response, row, by=0)
    write.table(merged, file = "temp_and_cases.csv", append = TRUE, sep = ",")
}
```

`row` is the current row from the `cases_by_region` df.
 `response` is the result of the api_call.
`cases_by_region` was obtained -> `cases_by_region <- read_csv("cases_by_region.csv")` and looks like this :

```
State | admin2 |province_state | lat | longcombined_key | day | number_of_cases | total_cases
Abbreviation
Alabama | Autauga | Alabama | 32.53953 | -86.64408 | Autauga, Alabama, US | 2020-04-03 | 12 |   72 | AL |
```

the response from the api is a csv that looks like that :

```
Address,Date time,Minimum Temperature,Maximum Temperature,Temperature,Dew Point,Relative Humidity,Heat Index,Wind Speed,Wind Gust,Wind Direction,Wind Chill,Precipitation,Precipitation Cover,Snow Depth,Visibility,Cloud Cover,Sea Level Pressure,Weather Type,Latitude,Longitude,Resolved Address,Name,Info,Conditions
"32.53953,-86.64408","04/03/2020",7.5,25.2,15.7,8.4,67.85,,8.7,,35.79,,0,0,,15.8,7.1,1016.3,"",32.53953,-86.64408,"32.53953,-86.64408","","","Clear"
```

So far the code I wrote indeed appends to the csv file but not at all in the expected way (strange headers merging and no row values...) :

```
"Row.names","Address","Date time","Minimum Temperature","Maximum Temperature","Temperature","Dew Point","Relative Humidity","Heat Index","Wind Speed","Wind Gust","Wind Direction","Wind Chill","Precipitation","Precipitation Cover","Snow Depth","Visibility","Cloud Cover","Sea Level Pressure","Weather Type","Latitude","Longitude","Resolved Address","Name","Info","Conditions","y"
```

This is the part to apply the function get_temp to every row of `cases_by_region`

```
temps <- apply(cases_by_region, 1, get_temp)
```

How can I merge row and the response from the api side by side, and then append to each created line to the `temp_and_cases.csv` file in the right csv format ( an extra issue is that the column names should be appended to the csv file only on the first api call) ?

Comment: Are there any variables common between `response` and `row` ? Do you need to `merge` them or just `cbind` them?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
get_temp <- function(row) {
  uri <- build_uri(row$latitude, row$longitude, row$start_date)
  response <- readr::read_csv(uri)
  cbind(row, response)
}

temps <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(cases_by_region, 
                               seq(nrow(cases_by_region))), get_temp))
write.csv(temps, "temp_and_cases.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Using `asplit` we split each row into different dataframes, pass each row to `get_temp` function, `cbind` `row` and `response` and finally combine them into one dataframe.

We can write csv only once at the end for entire file.

Comment: Im getting  ```Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors``` when trying to ```build_uri``` with row now. Moreover I dont think it's a good idea to write the csv at the end of the whole process because ```cases_by_region``` is huge and the third party api can timeout and fail. Id rather find a solution that appends incrementally to the file

Comment: @DavidGeismar I updated the answer using `split` instead of `asplit`. I think writing csv incrementally would slow down the process drastically and is inefficient. If you are worried about timeout, introduce `Sys.sleep()` with few seconds in `get_temp`.